# Event custom event from main vue instance, listen from component

Tags: vue.js

Pretty new to vue js here,

Just want to know if is it possible to emit a custom event from the main vue instance (parent) and the components could listen to that custom event and act accordingly when that event is triggered?

I want to trigger a custom event on vue instance **mounted** lifecycle function then all components can initialize themselves.

ex.

Main vue instance

```
new Vue( {
    el : '#main-app',
    mounted : function() {
       this.$emit( 'init-app' );
    }
} );
```

Then on the various components, it can listen for the **'init-app'** custom event then act accordingly when it is triggered or emitted.

Not sure how to do this coz in vue js event listeners are attached to the html tags? can an event listener or a function in a component be triggered by just the emitting of the event from the parent alone?

Note: I'm using vue js 2.0.3
and my components are global, they are not inline

ex.

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
   template: '#component-template'
});
```

I could add more components later on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to put the initialization codes of each components to the components themselves, I don't want to put them on the main vue instance.

Comment: Are you thinking of using $on and $emit as explained in the docs?

Comment: Again I'm pretty new to vue js, can you please give me an example on how to achieve what I want based on my question above? not sure how to implement what I want, showing some code samples is really helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to initialize your child components is to use `created:` life-cycle hook for each of your child components.

Reason: It is quite possible that your child component may not be instantiated when you send your `init-app` event from the parent component. So, it will never get initialized.

Additional note on events: If you are sending an event from child component to parent component, you should use `this.$parent.$emit("my-event-code")` and receive it on the parent side as `this.$on("my-event-code")`. I figured it out recently after hours of trying various methods.

So, if you are trying to send an `init-app` event from parent to child, you might have to listen on child component as `this.$parent.$on("init-app", ...)` - I haven't verified this yet, this is my current understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mani, can you please provide a code sample of your solution? btw I've updated the question, I failed to inform that my components are global components, not inline to the main vue instance.

Comment: @Jplus2 I did not realize you have global components that are unrelated to each other. In this case, you have only one option - create an **event bus** as explained here: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: Thank you @Mani, you lead me to the solution, basically vue components has indeed lifecycle events similar to vue instances, it was foolish of me as I did not tested it. The docs though didn't explicitly mention about components having life cycle hooks, anyways, I used the *mounted* hook as it is triggered after the component is rendered.

Comment: Also additional note, for global components, you must register the component first, before instantiating your main vue instance, I find it odd but you half to do this in order for this to work.

Comment: @Jplus2 I am glad you could figure it out. Regarding multiple global Vue instances connected via event bus communication, are you sure it is something you want to do? There may be a cost for every Vue instance in terms of memory footprint and CPU cycles to maintain the state, which may make your app sluggish to end-user. The core reason I moved from Angular2 to Vue recently is because of its minimal footprint and speed, which may be lost with multiple Vue instances.

Comment: Basically @Mani I'm just learning vue js and I choose vue over angular coz unlike angular, vue is very easy to incorporate to existing apps, Angular is opinionated and you have to do it by Angular's way, I don't have that privilege coz I am working on existing apps.

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me, which isn't well explained in the Vue.js documentation. Thanks.